# Uploading a file generated by Java applet to FTP

Tags: java, html, file-upload, ftp, japplet

I have a Java applet embedded in an HTML page that is intended to generate .csv files based on user responses to questions in the applet. The goal is to have a master data file that can be retrieved and updated by the applet, and then uploaded again, overwriting the original file.

Right now, I'm using FTP to store the applet .jar file and the master .csv data file. Is this the best solution? If so, how do I upload the new .csv file in place of the old .csv file strictly through the applet (no file will be downloaded to a local destination)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using http?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the best solution?

If the applet can upload to your site, so can an hacker. Look forward to seeing entire repositories of child pornography appear on the server, and the authorities appear on your doorstep - asking you to 'please explain..'.

Or to put that another, more succinct way.  No.

Instead, the applet should get in contact with a servlet, JSP, PHP, ..ASP (whatever) page that updates the CSV.